# How to detect a login event with Rails and devise in order to push login event into datalayer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I want to track the login event with GTM in my rails app running devise for authentication. I need to push the login event into the datalayer :

```
 window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
 window.dataLayer.push({
    'event' : 'login',
    'authenticationMethod' : 'email',
    'userId' : 'abc123' //this should be replaced with an actual ID
 });
```

However on the rails/devise side of things, I am unsure about how to detect that the user just logged in and run the above javascript code.

Could you explain how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can [customize Devise Session Controller](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-controllers) to include your Javascript snippet into the view for the action after user is logged in (`SessionsController.create`) It's the same way Devise does "Signed in successfully." flash message.